# undefined reference to _imp__GetDIBits@28 with GetDIBits function

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, linker, qt-creator

I'm trying to use the **GetDIBits** function with C++ (with QtCreator) on Windows. The code compiles but can not link with the error

> undefined  reference to _imp__GetDIBits@28

I tried to link add

> LIBS = C:/MinGW/lib/libws2_32.a

to my .pro file but nothing changed.
is it the correct library or another one ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link with `Gdi32.lib`.

In general, to figure out which library to link with, look up the API on msdn.microsoft.com and then scroll to the bottom of the page for the headers and lib requirements.

Example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: made it. Thank you again